# How to chance the linguagem in Flutter with a button

Tags: flutter, localization, internationalization

I have an App in Flutter and I'm using the localization package to translate the app into multiple languages, and so far, everything is working fine. After each word/String, I add a .i18n(), and the app picks up the system language to start. However, I had the idea to allow the user to change the language within the app if they want to later. I've searched everywhere and couldn't find a function to change the language using this library. I even tried using easy_localizations, but I would have to change my entire code and structure. Speaking of structure, this is my app's structure:

```
class AppWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  const AppWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    LocalJsonLocalization.delegate.directories = ['lib/assets/i18n'];

    return MultiProvider(

      providers: [

        ChangeNotifierProvider(

          create: (_) => ImageHelper(),

        ),

        ChangeNotifierProvider(

          create: (_) => ThemeProvider(),

        ),

      ],

      child: Consumer<ThemeProvider>(

        builder: (context, themeProvider, child) {

          SizeConfig().init(context);

          return MaterialApp.router(

            themeMode: themeProvider.themeMode,

            theme: MyThemes.lightScheme,

            darkTheme: MyThemes.darkScheme,

            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,

            scrollBehavior: CustomBehavior(),

            title: 'app_name'.i18n(),

            localizationsDelegates: [

              GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,

              GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,

              GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,

              LocalJsonLocalization.delegate

            ],

            supportedLocales: const [

              Locale('da', 'DK'),

              Locale('de', 'DE'),

              Locale('el', 'GR'),

              Locale('en', 'US'),

              Locale('en', 'GB'),

              Locale('es', 'ES'),

              Locale('fi', 'FI'),

              Locale('fr', 'FR'),

              Locale('it', 'IT'),

              Locale('nl', 'NL'),

              Locale('no', 'NO'),

              Locale('pl', 'PL'),

              Locale('pt', 'PT'),

              Locale('pt', 'BR'),

              Locale('sv', 'SE'),

            ],

            routerConfig: Modular.routerConfig,

          );

        },

      ),

    );

  }

}

class AppScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {

  @override

  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {

        PointerDeviceKind.touch,

        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,

      };

}
```

And this is the settings screen where I was trying to change the language:

```
class SettingsPage extends StatefulWidget {

  const SettingsPage({super.key});

  @override

  State<SettingsPage> createState() => _SettingsPageState();

}

class _SettingsPageState extends State<SettingsPage> {

  bool _isLoading = false;

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Locale currentLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);

    String? currentLanguage = currentLocale.countryCode;

    final sizeW = SizeConfig.blockSizeW!;

    return Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(

        title: Text('settings_page'.i18n()),

        centerTitle: true,

      ),

      body: _isLoading

          ? Center(

              child: CircularProgressIndicator(

                color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.outline,

              ),

            )

          : Padding(

              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: sizeW * 4),

              child: ListView(

                physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),

                children: [

                  SizedBox(height: sizeW * 8),

                  Row(

                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,

                    children: [

                      Flexible(

                        child: Text(

                          'system_language'.i18n(),

                          style: TextStyle(

                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,

                            fontSize: sizeW * 4.5,

                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,

                          ),

                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,

                        ),

                      ),

                      CountryCodePicker(

                        onChanged: (CountryCode? code) async {

                          if (code != null) {

                            setState(() {

                              currentLanguage = code.code;

                            });

                          }

                        },

                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,

                        initialSelection: currentLanguage,

                        hideMainText: true,

                        showCountryOnly: true,

                        countryFilter: const [

                          'DK',

                          'DE',

                          'GR',

                          'US',

                          'GB',

                          'ES',

                          'FI',

                          'FR',

                          'IT',

                          'NL',

                          'NO',

                          'PL',

                          'PT',

                          'BR',

                          'SE',

                        ],

                      ),

                    ],

                  ),

                  SizedBox(height: sizeW * 4),

                ],

              ),

            ),

    );

  }

}
```

Like I said I try to use others packages but didnt work